# Commerce view of node checkout hides unpublished content, therefore can't relist

Tags: views, commerce

I'm using commerce node checkout and have enabled the predefined view, `Commerce Node Checkout Expire Posts (Content)` to give customers a list of content they've paid to publish.

The problem is, when the content expires and is unpublished, it disappears from the view output. This is problematic because that view contains the 'relist' button, meaning that customers can't relist expired content.

Has anyone found a workaround for this? (Or maybe I'm missing something?)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

1. In the view, go to: Advanced > Other > Query Settings.
2. Switch on `Disable SQL rewriting`.

Unpublished nodes should now be visible in the view.